# Python script in windows uses no time between measure points

Tags: python, windows, time, file-io

I've created a little program to transfer files (client/server) using sockets. In my sending function, I've measured the time needed to perform some tasks, in order to estimate the average speed of the transfer.

```
while (l):
    start_time = time.time()
    self.__sendData(l)
    acc += len(l)
    self.__setProgress(acc)
    l = f.read(1024)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("longitud: " + str(len(l)))
    print("total: " + str(elapsed_time))
    self.__setSpeed(len(l), elapsed_time)
```

Here you can see that I have an `acc`(umulator) var in order to calculate the total progress of the transfer. I read the next `1024` bytes of the file, and calculate the time it needed to perform these operations. My function `__setSpeed` just calculates the average speed using the latest `50` instant-speeds.

This **works fine in Linux**, no problem at all. However, when I run this in Windows, I found the following output:

[image]

As you can see, there're lots of times that the `time for transfer and file read` is exactly `zero`. I can't understand why this happens, because:

1. I could imagine (just a guess) that in Windows, the file may be buffered so the `readtime` of the file becomes 0. Ok.
2. The `sendData` function may be really fast, as it's a really small amount. Ok, but really zero?
3. Plus we should add some really small amounts for the other commands to execute, like control structures, inside my functions, and so forth.

So basically my questions are two:

1. **Why is this happening?** Should I use another method to measure it?
2. **Which method would be accurate and would fit to be used in both OS**, Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, `time.time` is based on [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimeasfiletime). We can get the resolution of this clock with `time.get_clock_info`. For the system clock it calls [`GetSystemTimeAdjustment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimeadjustment). The default resolution is 15.625 ms:

```
>>> time.get_clock_info('time').resolution
0.015625
```

[`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) should solve your problem. In Windows it's based on [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904). To get the resolution of this clock, `get_clock_info` calls [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905). It's typically 100 ns:

```
>>> time.get_clock_info('perf_counter').resolution
1e-07
```